# How to use subprocess to obtain terminal error information?

Tags: python, subprocess, selenium-ide

I am using subprocess to execute selenium-side-runner. I want to get the error information of the terminal and analyze the cause of the error with code.

```
result = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "selenium-side-runner",
        "--server",
        settings.SELENIUM_ADDRESS,
        file_path,
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
try:
    outs, errs = result.communicate(timeout=600)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    result.kill()
    outs, errs = result.communicate()
```

But using this method, I can't get the error message like output in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `stderr`:

```
result = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "selenium-side-runner",
        "--server",
        settings.SELENIUM_ADDRESS,
        file_path,
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your method to get the output from the terminal.